# When I add has_many, some data is suddently not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I have 3 models, Challenge, Pun, User (managed by Clearance gem)

A User can create a Challenge. A Challenge contains many puns. A User can also create a Pun.

Everything is fine until I set a Pun to belong_to a User, then suddenly Puns are no longer saved.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Clearance::User
  has_many :challenges
  has_many :puns
end

class Challenge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :puns, :dependent => :delete_all
  belongs_to :user
end

class Pun < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my PunController I have tried to establish the current_user id

```
  def create
    @pun = @challenge.puns.create(pun_params)
    @pun.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    redirect_to @challenge
  end

  private

  def set_challenge
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
  end

  def pun_params
    params[:pun].permit(:pun_text,:user_id)
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, but seems like Users don't want to be associated with more than one thing, particularly if nested. Is this a Clearance issue?

DB setup:

```
  create_table "challenges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_challenges_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "puns", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "pun_text"
    t.bigint "challenge_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["challenge_id"], name: "index_puns_on_challenge_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_puns_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "tagline"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", limit: 128
    t.string "confirmation_token", limit: 128
    t.string "remember_token", limit: 128
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email"
    t.index ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in you currrent code you don't save user_id after setting it. And if you do not expect creation to fail you can do "create!".
So you can try:

```
def create
  @challenge.puns.create!(pun_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))

  redirect_to @challenge
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simply `hidden_field` like in the form

```
<%= object.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

it won't work without user session because the relationship does not optional, and remove this line from the controller

```
@pun.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
```

and redirect

```
redirect_to @pun
```

it will work